# Insert post Blogger API failed in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, httprequest, blogger, blogspot

hi all iam trying insert post using GAS but failed.. can you tell me what im wrong... thx in advance....

here  my code

```
`function sendHttpPost() {
 var API_KEY = 'my api key';
 var scope = "http://www.blogger.com/feeds/";       
 var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("blogger");
 oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
 oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
 oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
 oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
 oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  var payload = 
    {
  "kind": "blogger#post",
  "blog": {
    "id": "486683248036684073"
  },
  "title": "A new post",
  "content": "With <b>exciting</b> content..."
}
  var options =
    {
      "contentType":"application/json",
      "oAuthServiceName" : "blogger",
      "oAuthUseToken" : "always",
      "method" : "POST",
      "payload" : payload
    };

  var respon = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/486683248036684073/posts?key="+API_KEY, options);
```

and here is error message

> Request failed for returned code 400. Server response: { "error": {
>   "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "parseError", "message":
>   "Parse Error" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Parse Error" } }

Comment: The error is pretty vague but I'd start with replacing the content with some simple text of say one line.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to use oauth1 when [oauth2 is required](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#auth).
there already is a unanswered request about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589152/retrieve-blog-feeds-using-google-oauth-2-0-and-scribe).
Implementing oauth 2 with Google app script is really a pain, so I made an attempt to build a library that could answer the need ([dioxygen library](https://sites.google.com/a/ousset.net/orgasm-library/home/dioxygen-library)) - it work a little bit like the [oauth2 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) but it's less pretty.
With a little work you should be able to adapt it to your need with blogger.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Harold's library, but after successfully retrieving OAuth token, I ended up with the same error.

But, when I issued the same JSON request as in my script through the API Explorer, it was processed:
https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/insert

[UPDATE]

I am taking it back. This code works. I just replaced the **payload** variable and put the JSON request straight into URL fetch **options**. So there was some problem with passing that **payload** variable into **options** variable.

```
function testBlogger() {

  var payload =
      {
        "kind": "blogger#post",
        "blog": {
          "id": "YOUR_BLOG_ID"
        },
        "title": "New post",
        "content": "With content..."
      };

  var options =
      {
        "method" : "post",
        "headers" : { "Authorization" : "Bearer YOUR_ACTIVE_TOKEN"},
        "contentType" : "application/json",
        "payload" : '{ "kind": "blogger#post", "blog": { "id": "YOUR_BLOG_ID" }, "title": "New post", "content": "With content..." }'
      };

  try {

    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/YOUR_BLOG_ID/posts",
      options);

    Logger.log(result);

  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e);
  }
}
```